# How to use get_file_contents in PHP when authorization is needed for URI?

Tags: php, json, https, get, docusignapi

I'm making a request to retrieve a JSON file to a server at a particular secure DocuSign `uri`. However, unless I put in the authorization information (which I do have), I am unable to have the file returned.

```
<?php
    $json = file_get_contents("https://example.docusign.com/sensitiveIDs/moreID");
    echo $json
?>
```

Where would I put in authorization information for the specific server/username/password/other info needed to access the particular DocuSign server using a method like this in PHP? Is there a better method to use for this scenario in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the authorization is implemented. If its basic or digest HTTP authentication then specify it in the URL:

```
file_get_contents("https://$USER:$PASSWORD@example.docusign.com/sensitiveIDs/moreID");
```

Cookie based authentication is a lot more difficult (and probably easier to use Curl or even a more complex system like Guzzle. If its oauth2, then you probably want an [oauth2 library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/web-app).

Comment: (just had a google and its Oauth2 - you've got a lot of learning ahead).

Comment: Can you please give a basic example? This didn't clear up much and the DocuSign documentation only covers HTML examples

Comment: The point I was trying to make is that there are no simple examples of oauth2. Sadly the link I provided is one of the better explanations

Comment: OAuth2 is supported, but CURL works just fine. There are code examples on the developer website https://www.docusign.com/developer-center

Comment: No, Oauth2 and Curl are not complimentary - Oauth2 is an protocol implemented on top of HTTP - Curl merely provides an API for working with HTTP. From https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/recipes/signing-from-your-app : "Use this technique when your app has authenticated the user and wants him or her to sign immediately from within your app."

Answer (score 0):

Your call needs to include authentication to make the GET call to retrieve the file.

If your app is initiated by a human use Oauth to retrieve access and refresh tokens. Then included the access token with the GET request.

If your app is a "system app" that wants to autonomously retrieve the file, then you should authenticate by using `X-DocuSign-Authentication` -- include the following header in your HTTPS request. Since the request is HTTPS, the content is encrypted on the wire:

```
X-DocuSign-Authentication: <DocuSignCredentials><Username>{name}</Username><Password>{password}</Password><IntegratorKey>{integrator_key}</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>
```

Replace {name} with your email address (no braces), etc.

**The bottom line** is that you can't use the `file_get_contents` Php method. Instead, you'd do something like the following:

Use https://github.com/rmccue/Requests or a similar library to help with the **https** request. (http is not allowed due to security issues.)

(untested code)

```
$url = $base_url . $the_url_section_for_this_call 
$headers = array('X-DocuSign-Authentication' => 
'<DocuSignCredentials><Username>your_name</Username><Password>your_password</Password><IntegratorKey>your_integrator_key</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>');
$request = Requests::get($url, $headers);
# Check that the call succeeded (either 200 or 201 depending on the method
$status_code = $request->status_code;
if ($status_code != 200 && $status_code != 201) {
    throw new Exception('Problem while calling DocuSign');
}
$json = $request->body;
```